# Android TabActivity with Toolbar - setSupportActionBar() unknow

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-toolbar, android-tabactivity

Is it possible to use `setSupportActionBar()` in an `TabActivity`?
Extending with `AppCompatActivity` is not possible...

```
public class TabHost extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // this is unkown
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //also
```

Do I have to switch from `TabActivity` to `FragmentTabHost`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can't. You have to extend `AppCompatActivity`, and you shouldn't use `TabActivity` in the first place. It was deprecated long time ago. You should use a solution based on a `ViewPager` and `Fragment`s to achieve the same behavior

Comment: i need compatiblitiy till API 10. Is this possible?

Comment: I have Tabs with own Classes (Layout etc.) this is really hard to switch over

Comment: it is not hard, maybe it is gonna take sometime, but I think it is a price you should be willing to pay